# How to open user's Outlook based on selected email subject

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, office-interop, office-automation

So what I'm trying to do:
User has a desktop application with a grid. A grid basically shows him a list of email subjects which were sent to a defined email address. When a user double clicks on a row in the grid, outlook opens an email with the subject from the grid.

In order to read emails and show them in the grid, I think something like MailKit library could be used. But I'm not sure how to open specific email in outlook. Is it possible to pass something like email id (or subject) via command line and open a specific email or outlook interop could be used for that?

PS. Not quite sure if my question is clear enough, but has to start from something...

Comment: How is the grid populated? Where does the data come from? What do you know about the messages? Just the subject? Or also Outlook entry id and/or MIME message id? How do you deal with duplicate subject names?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the following command line:

```
outlook.exe /select outlook:{ENTRYID}
```

Also you may consider automating Outlook from your application for display the item with a specific ID (see the `EntryID` property). The [NameSpace.GetItemFromID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getitemfromid) method returns a Microsoft Outlook item identified by the specified entry ID (if valid). After getting an instance of the item you just need to call the [MailItem.Display](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.display) method.

Comment: how do I know EntryID, is it possible to see it in outlook UI somewhere?

Comment: You can use low-level explorer tools such as MFCMAPI or Outlook for exploring Outlook internals and see the actual EntryID property values.